# Sum of $n$ numbers divisible by $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a collection of (not necessarily distinct) integers, how large must the collection be to guarantee that for a particular $n$, there is a subcollection of $n$ numbers summing to a multiple of $n$?

A glance shows that for any $n$, at least $2n-1$ are required, since if we have a collection of $n-1$ 0's and $n-1$ 1's, then there is no way to sum to a multiple of $n$. Is there an elegant way to prove $2n-1$ is always sufficient?

Comment: If we have a subcollection of $0$s... then isn't $0$ a multiple of $n$?

Comment: Just to clarify:  you require that we use $n$ numbers, yes?  Not $≤n$.  Thus , having $n-1$ $0's$ doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, this is the content of the [Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem).

Comment: Here is the original Erdos paper https://bolyai.hu/~p_erdos/1961-25.pdf

Comment: Yes, I did mean exactly $n$ numbers, no less. Thanks everyone for linking me to resources!

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant proof of this using the Chevalley Warning theorem which easily proves it for prime $n$ (then a multiplicative property is proved for the rest).

See [this, section 4. (page 11)](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400ChevalleyWarning.pdf)